# How to get specific date interval for every month in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate some percentage etc. between 1st and 13th of every month.
Like JAN 1st to JAN 13th Do some calculation. Similarly for every month I have to make the calculation for the first 13 days. How to get the first 13 days or any number of days in MySQL?

Comment: Please show some data and table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column of date data type it could be like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(date_column) AS mnth,
       SUM(etc) AS col1, 
       SUM(etc2) AS col2
FROM tbl
WHERE DAY(date_column) BETWEEN 1 AND 13
GROUP BY MONTH(date_column)
```

Comment: Thanks. There's no need of sample data.